# EC2 Spot Instance Substitute for Dedicated / On-Demand?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I recently found out about the pricing for the spot instances and they were dirt cheap. The difference in paying for a spot instance and on-demand / reserved is quite large.

Since the price for the small instance runs about 3 cents and hour, I was wondering if this would be reliable for be used as a dedicated LAMP server. Of course, it would require me set the bid up high for a almost-guaranteed chance of me having an instance at all times.

However, I'm not sure in terms of reliability. Sure, I would be saving a few bucks with this, but I am not sure if it is safe for uptime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the price history, it's usually predictable within a certain range. If you use a spot instead you need to ensure the instance is capable of being terminated at any time without data loss, you simply cannot assure this won't happen.

If you intend to use the instance for time, you might be better off considering a reserved instance instead for 1 or 3 years to save overall running costs. You're not looking at that big a difference between a 3 year and spot instances, it's about 20% more, roughly.